# How to use string as an expression

Tags: string, vbscript, type-conversion

I have constructed a VBScript command in a string and I like to use that string as a normal VBScript code. How can I convert that string to a literal VBScript code? Any help would be great.

See below the code where I am using `For Loop` to create an expression. When I use the `msgbox` to print the result, I would like to get the calculated values of `expStr` and not the string as-is.

```
For i = 0 to x
    expStr =   expStr  & "":""  & Mid(OrigStr,ArrSt(" & i & "),ArrEn(" & i + 1 & ")-ArrSt(" & i & "))
    i = i + 1
Next

result = expStr 

msgbox result
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Eval, which takes an expression and returns its value, Execute, which takes a group of statements and executes them in local scope, and ExecuteGlobal which executes them in global scope.

e.g. You can save the reusable code in a .vbs file and use it as follows

```
Set oFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = oFs.OpenTextFile(strFile)
code = oFile.ReadAll
oFile.Close
ExecuteGlobal code
```

You have also Eval, which takes an expression and returns its value, Execute, which takes a group of statements and executes them in local scope, and ExecuteGlobal which executes them in global scope.

In ASP you can inlude code like this

```
<!-- #include File="routines.asp" -->
```

Comment: Or can directly ExecuteGlobal result